# How to remote debug a rails 3.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pry

I have a bug in my application which is only happening on 'stage' but not locally. I would like to use a debugger and set a breakpoint so I can debug the application on stage.

Locally I use pry and even got the pry-remote to work locally but couldn't get it to work on the server.

I don't mind using the regular debugger or pry for the debugging.

The problem I am usually hit with:
ArgumentError (non-absolute home)

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean on "stage"? Is it an environment?

Comment: You know, "staging"... It's what we use to deploy to first before deploying to production.

Comment: Yes, I know staging but you called it "stage". ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're definitely not putting this out into a production environment while you're testing it, I would recommend the `better_errors` Gem.  It's definitely not for a production site though as it would expose some serious security issues

If you include it in the `:development` group it will give you a console in the webpage whenever an error is occurring.

If it's not raising a fatal error, then you can throw the `raise` method anywhere you want to act like a breakpoint, you won't be able to continue on, but it's useful to help do pry like stuff in the webpage.

There's a good guide by Ryan Bates

http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel

Answer (score 0):

One solution to reproduce the error locally is to start your server in the same environment that is failing.

```
$ RAILS_ENV=staging script/server
```